# What could I have like parameter to @HostBinding decorator?

Tags: angular, angular2-hostbinding

Can't find documentation for it.

From examples I got 3 cases:

- @HostBinding("**attr**.something")
- @HostBinding("**class**.something")
- @HostBinding("**style**.something")

but is there more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per written in this [link](https://medium.com/@ttemplier/component-composition-in-angular2-part-1-33f50f402906#.hrxvsitg9)
by Thierry Templier who is also active in this group if I remember correctly :) Picture is from post from that website.

[image: HostBinding]

Answer (score 7):

> **propertyName**: references a property of the host with the propertyName name.

```
@HostBinding('value') value:string;
```

> **attr.attributeName**: references an attribute of the host with the attributeName name. The initial value is set to the associated directive property. Setting a value in the property updates the attribute on the corresponding HTML element. Using the null value at this level removes the attribute on the HTML element.

```
@HostBinding('attr.role') role:string;
```

> **style.styleName**: links a directive property to a style of the HTML element.

```
@HostBinding('style.width.px') width:number;
```

> **class.className**: links a directive property to a class name of the HTML element. If the value is true, the class is added otherwise removed.

```
@HostBinding('class.someClass') condition:boolean;
```